# Magento 2 : How to disable/enable shipping method based on Region/State

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am working on magento 2.1.3. I need to disable or enable one or more shipping method based on State/Region.

Is there any possibility without purchasing a 3rd party plugin.?

Answer (score 2):

We faced a similar thing, some weeks ago.

If you need to disable a shipping method based on user's **Country**, you can configure this from Magento admin panel (I suppose you already know this).

If you need to disable a method based on the **Region** you need to make a **little module**.

I try to give you main points below, supposing you want to **disable flatrate** shipping method.

---

File `app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/etc/module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">

  <module name="Vendor_ShippingRestriction" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <!-- Not sure about these lines below if they are really required -->
    <module name="Magento_Shipping"/>
    <module name="Magento_OfflineShipping"/>
  </module>

</config>
```

---

File `app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/etc/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

  <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
    <plugin name="disableFlaterateShipping"
        sortOrder="1" 
        type="Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Plugin\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\FlatratePlugin"
        />
  </type>

</config>
```

---

File `app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/Plugin/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/FlatratePlugin`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Plugin\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier;

use \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate;

class FlatratePlugin
{
  /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
   */
  protected $_appState;

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
   */
  protected $_checkoutSession;

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Region
   */
  protected $_regionModel;

  /**
   * Constructor
   * 
   * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
   * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
   * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $regionModel
   */
  public function __construct
  (
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Region $regionModel
  ) {
    $this->_appState = $appState;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_regionModel = $regionModel;
    return;
  }

  /**
   * After isActive
   * 
   * @param Flatrate $subject
   * @param $result
   * @return bool
   * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
   */
  public function afterIsActive(Flatrate $subject, $result)
  {
    // Leave active on admin area
    $areaCode = $this->_appState->getAreaCode();
    if ($areaCode === \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMIN ||
        $areaCode === \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
      return $result;
    }

    // Get region code
    $regionId = $this->_checkoutSession
      ->getQuote()
      ->getShippingAddress()
      ->getRegionId();

    $regionCode = $this->_regionModel
      ->load($regionId)
      ->getData('code');

    // Enabled region codes
    $enabledRegions = [ 
      /* List of enabled regions codes */
    ];

    // Show shipping method only for some regions
    if (!in_array($regionCode, $enabledRegions)) {
      return false;
    }

    return $result;
  }

}
```

---

It should works I guess. I'm not sure since I changed it a little, for reporting it here. Let me know if you find some errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want disable or enable shipping method for example **UPS** or **flatrate** based on Region ID then yo need to rewrite class: `Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping` in your custom module and add this code in method `collectCarrierRates()`

```
    $regionId = $request->getDestRegionId();
    $yourRegionId1 = 569;
    $yourRegionId2 = 583;
    if($regionId == $yourRegionId1 && $carrierCode == "ups"){
        $result = false;
    }

    if($regionId != $yourRegionId2 && $carrierCode == "flatrate"){
        $result = false;
    }
```

Note: You can take the region id from table: `directory_country_region`